# How to create a SecondaryTile on Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, secondary-live-tile

I'm trying to create a Tile on the Windows Phone start screen. The following code used to work but now it doesn't. I didn't change anything.

```csh
    private async static void CreateTile()
    {
        try
        {
            SecondaryTile tileData = new SecondaryTile()
            {
                TileId = "MyTileID",
                DisplayName = "My App Name",
                TileOptions = TileOptions.ShowNameOnLogo,
            };

            tileData.VisualElements.Square150x150Logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Resources/Images/Tiles/150150.png", UriKind.Absolute);
            tileData.VisualElements.ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo = true;

            await tileData.RequestCreateAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Now it's failing with the error message:

```csh
The parameter is incorrect.
```

and the following Stack Trace:

```csh
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at My.Namespace.SplashPage.<CreateTile>d__f.MoveNext()
```

I even get the error when I comment everything out, for example:

```csh
SecondaryTile tileData = new SecondaryTile()
{
    //TileId = "MyTileID",
    //DisplayName = "My App Name",
    //TileOptions = TileOptions.ShowNameOnLogo,
};

//tileData.VisualElements.Square150x150Logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Resources/Images/Tiles/150150.png", UriKind.Absolute);
//tileData.VisualElements.ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo = true;

await tileData.RequestCreateAsync();
```

So I don't know what parameter is incorrect. What could be causing this? How can I fix it?

Comment: Try using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn251589.aspx) constructor or setting all the corresponding properties (Arguments is what I think might be the problem). Also, is this a Silverlight or Xaml/WinPRT app?

Comment: It's a WinRT app. I'll give your suggestion a try in the morning. Thanks.

Comment: Did it work for you? I might use FlipTileData.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    if (SecondaryTile.Exists(tileID)) await tileData.UpdateAsync();
    else await tileData.RequestCreateAsync();
```